# Pandas groupby issue

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, pandas-groupby

Have a quick issue with using dataframe `groupby()` function. I have a BS4 html table to be parsed into Pandas dataframe and then the aim is to nest the multiple rows for a 'Field' using `Groupby()`. Not sure why I get the

> 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby''

error. Is my `str(table)` incorrect?

Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


starttime = datetime.now()

#Agent detail to prevent scraping bot detection
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
header = {'User-Agent' : user_agent }



# Webpage connection
html = "http://factpages.npd.no/ReportServer?/FactPages/TableView/field
_production_monthly&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:Parameters
=f&Top100=True&IpAddress=108.171.128.174&CultureCode=en"

r=requests.get(html, headers=header)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'a133'})


#Pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))


j = (df.groupby(["Field (Discovery)","NPDID information carrier"], 
    as_index=False)
      .apply(lambda x: x[[ 'Year','Month','Oil - saleable [mill Sm3]','Gas - 
      saleable [bill Sm3]','NGL - saleable [mill Sm3]','Condensate - 
      saleable [mill Sm3]','Oil equivalents - saleable [mill Sm3]','Water - 
      wellbores [mill Sm3]' ]].to_dict('r'))
     .reset_index(drop=True)
     .rename(columns={0: 'MonthlyProduction'})
     .to_json(orient='records'))

print(j)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(j), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Your "Webpage connection" shows "Reporting Services Error" and no table exists. Is this an internal thing you have access to?

Comment: Odd, this is a public available service. I have just used the url as the query rather than using a ssrs frontend. I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html `pd.read_html` returns the list of dataframes (one dataframe for each table). So, you need to choose which one you want to group. Like:

```
# for the first one:
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt seem to change the outcome. It is bringing the table back as a data frame but when groupby function is used thats when the issue arises.

Comment: So, when you call pd.read_html(...)[0].groupby(...) you get  exactly the same exception?

Comment: apologies, just re-ran. It is a Keyerror on the field I tried to groupby.  `\groupby.py", line 2842, in _get_group
    raise KeyError(gpr) KeyError: 'MyField'`

Comment: Ok. Possibly your data frame doesn’t have such field. print df.columns to check the data

Comment: thanks for your help, needed to assign the headers row and then it has all started to work.. cheers